# Django calculated field and MVT usage

Tags: python, django, django-models, geolocation, django-views

So, I have an interesting problem that I'm having a hard time approaching.  I'm trying to intercept a queryset before sending a response to a template and add some instance/calculated variables.  I would normally add this to the model as a property, but one of the variables to make the calculation comes from user input via a POST request. Specifically, here is what I am trying to do (#4 is where I'm conceptually having the problem, everything else works fine including the zip code calculations):

1. Send zipcode, and speciality via POST to view
2. Get Lat Long coordinates from ZIP value
3. Filter organizations by specialty (included in POST request)
4. For each object in organization queryset returned, calculate the distance from the POST zipcode, and the model organization Lat,Long coordinates and return back to the template

**Model:**

```
class Organization(models.Model):
....
lat = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
long = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s - %s - %s - %s - %s - %s - %s " % (self.name, self.street,  self.streetaddtl, self. city, self.state, self.zip, self.external_website)


def save(self):
    if not self.lat or not self.long:
        addr = self.street + ' ' + self.city + ' ' + self.state + ' ' + self.zip
        self.lat, self.long = self.geocode(addr)
    super(Organization, self).save()

def geocode(self, address):
    address = urllib.quote_plus(address)
    request = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false" % address
    data = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(request).read())
    if data['status'] == 'OK':
        lat = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        lng = data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
        return Decimal(lat), Decimal(lng)`
```

**View:**

```
from search.lib.utils import geocode
....
def searchdoc(request):
if 'zip' in request.POST:
    dft_zip = request.POST['zip']
    zip_coord = geocode(dft_zip)
```

**Helper Function**

```
def distance(zip, b_lat, b_lng):
b_lat = Decimal(b_lat)
b_lng = Decimal(b_lng)
zipLat, zipLng = geocode_dec(zip)
zipLat = radians(zipLat)
b_lat = radians(b_lat)
long_diff = radians(zipLng - b_lng)
dist = (sin(zipLat) * sin(b_lat) +
        cos(zipLat) * cos(b_lat) * cos(long_diff))
return degrees(acos(dist))*69.09
```

**EDIT**
Using the below solution does allow me iterate and calculate the distance on the fly, however my goal in this is to somehow also sort the data back to the view based on the distance calculated.  The problem really stems from the fact that I can't create a property or mangager on the model that can accept the parameter supplied by the post request.  I'd like one dataset returned for the objects, rather then the query set and a separate dict. So in short, the answer below is good and works - however, I wasn't as clear on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the rest of your code??

You could loop through each of the organizations and calculate the distance and save it to an attribute on the Organization instance.

```
def searchdoc(request):
  if 'zip' in request.POST:
    dft_zip = request.POST['zip']
    zip_coord = geocode(dft_zip)
    organizations = Organization.objects.filter(some_filter_here=here)
    for org in organizations:
      org.distance = distance(dft_zip, org.lat, org.lng)
```

some things to note:

- if `geocode_dec` is making a call to google, this is bad news, network operations are extremely slow (and it appears you are already geocoding the zip in your view). If you have a lot of organizations in your queryset this will be bad for end user.  You could "cache" the zips by saving them in your db  with lat/lng.  So you could initially look in your db to see if you have the result then make a call to google if you don't, (since the lat/lng should never change for a zip)
- django has an extension called geodjango which provides an api for a spatial  database, both mysql and postgres have extensions to provide indexable, perfomant ways to filter based on distances,  additionally the geodjango api provides a [distance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.GeoQuerySet.distance) method that does what you are trying to do.  Def worth checking out to see if it could help to fufill your requirements

Comment: Thanks for the comments @dm03514 - I'll take note of the network and geodjango stuff.  Ad far as iterating over the queryset as demonstrated, is there then a way to order this by indexing the distance (lowest to highest)?  I like the queryset abilities to define filters, order by's etc and this will most likey require me to reorder into a Dict or List and send back to the context.  I was hoping for something within a model manager, class method or property.  Nonetheless, if this is the easiest way I'm all for it.  Thanks for the info!